# Enlive snippet giving me odd HTML

Tags: clojure, compojure, enlive

Problem: Enlive snippet making funky HTML

Visual reference of problem: http://i.imgur.com/FIOzgZv.png

See bottom of code snippet for strange HTML in question

```
(ns notebook.handler
  (:require [compojure.core :refer :all]
            [compojure.handler :as handler]
            [compojure.route :as route]
            [net.cgrand.enlive-html :as html]))

(html/defsnippet nav "templates/nav.html" [:*]
      [])

(html/deftemplate home-page "templates/base.html"
  []
   [:body] (html/prepend (nav)))

(defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/" [] (home-page))
  (route/resources "/")
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))

(def app
   (handler/site app-routes))
```

Contents of base.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel=stylesheet href="css/base.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Contents of nav.html:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>FlatNotes</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

HTML when localhost:3000 is visited:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="css/base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body><nav>
  <ul>
    <li>FlatNotes</li>
  </ul>

</nav><ul>
    <li>FlatNotes</li>
  </ul><li>FlatNotes</li>
  </body>

</html>
```

`(reduce str (html/emit* (nav)))` shows strange HTML meaning the problem occurs in `defsnippet` before `deftemplate`:

```
"<nav>\n  <ul>\n\t<li>FlatNotes</li>\n  </ul>\n\n</nav><ul>\n\t<li>FlatNotes</li>\n  </ul><li>FlatNotes</li>"
```

Maybe I'm mistaken about what `[:*]` does, or there's a fundamental misunderstanding, or there's a gotcha I'm unaware of. I've already reduced the code down to as minimal as I can so lolidk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:*` represents the universal selector. It matches every element in nav.html - `nav`, `ul`, and `li` - which means the nav snippet is:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>FlatNotes</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<ul>
  <li>FlatNotes</li>
</ul>

<li>FlatNotes</li>
```

The selector you pass to the snippet definition should point to the single, top level element of your snippet. If you change `:*` to match a single element (i.e. `:nav`), it ought to give you the snippet you're looking for.